# log_reuse_time_desc is ACTIVE_BACKUP_OR_RESTORE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

After dropping database replication and subscriber, the database's option

> log_resue_wait_desc

turned from replication to ACTIVE_BACKUP_OR_RESTORE.
I should I do to return it into NOTHING value

Comment: Log truncation cannot be done untill the full backup is completed, your server is in the middle of full backup, just wait when it finishes